# How is Schema Export/Update is triggered when building a web app?

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, fluent-nhibernate

I am building a sample app using Fluent NHibernate and every blog post i read about Fluent NHibernate say that the code below creates a schema and updates the database for me (Drops and Creats Database). But they never mention how this can be executed in Visual Studio.

```
var sessionFactory = FluentNHibernate
                .Cfg.Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(
                    MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(
                        c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ServicesDb"))) 
                .CurrentSessionContext("Web")
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<SqlCommandFactory>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true)) //Whne this is included
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Now when building a web app, all i can do is build my code. Is there a command i can execute in `Package Manager Console`. Like with Entity Framework Code First and Automatic Migration, i could just run `Update-Database -Force` and my database would be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use something similar to code first migrations, you should use [`Fluent Migrator`](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator). The concept is exaclty the same.

If you plan to export the schema with the code you're showing, you could use an IoC framework ([`Ninject`](http://www.ninject.org/), to be more specific) to do this work for you.

**EDIT**

You'll also need to change

```
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true))
```

by

```
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(true, true))
```

As your current configuration only allows creation but not update

Comment: I am using `Ninject` and the code i posted is within that configuration file, with a list of other `Bindings`.

Comment: @Komenge Mwandila: then you have to do nothing. As soon as that code executes the schema will be updated if necessary

Comment: When you say nothing, does that mean as soon as i build my code, the database should be updated or is it when i run debug?

Comment: @Komenge Mwandila: Database will be updated when the code runs (in any way, debugging or not), not when it is built.

Comment: I got this `There is already an object named 'AllUsers' in the database.`. Somehow that code is not checking if tables exists before execution. Just to clarify, `AllUsers` is a Table View i manually added.